# Selenium thinks button is clickable even when disabled

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, python, browser-automation, test-strategy

I'm having an issue where `Selenium` is saying a `button` is clickable even, when it's disabled.

I'm using `Selenium` with a website, where you have to select a date 1st and then time slot from a `drop-down list` before the `Book` button is clickable and will actually do anything. Before the date and time slot are chosen, the `button element` is

```html
 <div id="pt1:b2" class="x28o xfn p_AFDisabled p_AFTextOnly" style="width:300px;" _afrgrp="0" role="presentation"><a data-afr-fcs="false" class="xfp" aria-disabled="true" role="button"><span class="xfx">Book</span></a></div>
```

After the `date and time` slot are chosen, the `button` becomes:

```html
<div id="pt1:b2" class="x28o xfn p_AFTextOnly" style="width:300px;" _afrgrp="0" role="presentation"><a href="#" onclick="this.focus();return false" data-afr-fcs="true" class="xfp" role="button"><span class="xfx">Book</span></a></div>
```

I'm trying to use `this code` to wait for the button to be clickable

```python
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'pt1:b2')))
```

But `Selenium` is saying the `button is clickable` almost immediately upon the website loading even without a date or time slot chosen and the button being completely greyed out and `unclickable`.

I've tested this by checking the `timestamps` from after navigating to the `URL` and after waiting for the `button to be clickable`, and there's almost no delay. I've manually resorted to a try except loop and sleeping in between to be able to click the button successfully, but would rather figure out what's causing this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your HTML code doesn't contain `disabled` attribute to disable the field its being disabled by the class name `x28o xfn p_AFDisabled p_AFTextOnly` when it is enabled classname changes to `x28o xfn p_AFTextOnly`

Probably you should validate with the class name instead of using `elementisclickable`

Try this below

`wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class='x28o xfn p_AFTextOnly']")))`

Comment: This works, thank you! Just wondering though, does the aria-disabled="true" property matter at all for the disabled attribute?

Comment: I think no your button disable is controlled by javascript `aria-label` is used for accessibility purpose.This may help you https://www.w3.org/WAI/PF/aria/states_and_properties#aria-disabled